# PrimeFaces fileUpload doesn't work on IE<=9

Tags: java, jsf, file-upload, primefaces, jquery-file-upload

The problem occurs only in IE<=9. Everywhere else fileupload works perfectly.

I'm using PrimeFaces version: 3.4.2.
Upgrading to 4.0 doesn't change anything.

I've copied code from: [PrimeFaces FileUpload demo](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadAuto.jsf)

```
<h:form>

            <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadBean.listener}"
                mode="advanced" update="messages" auto="true" sizeLimit="100000"
                allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" />

            <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />

        </h:form>
```

I've even defined:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

On my page it's not working but on [FileUpload demo](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadAuto.jsf) page it's suprisingly working.

I've noticed this strange behaviour on IE <= 9 (Content-Length is 0 and Content-Type is not present - why?):

[image: my page request]

But on PrimeFaces page there is (the same browser - IE8/9):

[image: primefaces request]

I've also tried to set `enctype` to `multipart/form-data` and (like on PrimeFaces demo page) `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (which is default)

What can I do to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just resolved it.

The reason why it didn't work was that in the layout - XHTML masterpage there were included jquery and jquery.fileupload... but why IE<=9 didn't handle that I don't know (no errors/warnings in the console).

I just modified it to that below:

```
<o:conditionalComment if="gt IE 9">
    <script src="#{request.contextPath}/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="#{request.contextPath}/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="#{request.contextPath}/js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
</o:conditionalComment>
```

Now it works.

Comment: it's for OmniFaces @Xeon not primefaces I think so

Answer (score 0):

You could try to experiment with the primefaces.UPLOADER param if you haven't yet. I had to use

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
    <param-value>commons</param-value>
</context-param>
```

to make it work on IE8. Maybe that helps for you, too